# Making android app for a web app

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

There is a webapp made by a friend which uses a particular google apps domain (ex. abcd.ac.in) to authenticate users using google oauth2. I am making an android app for that webapp and he is providing me with json APIs for fetching data from webapp. The confusion we have is in authentication part.

How do i tell google that i want to authenticate using google account for that webapp? Do i need to register a new android app on google APIs console (i think yes?). But then how are the webapp and android app linked to same google oauth2 registered app?